# ggplot: using geom_smooth to plot variance

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a  time series plot with ggplot.  I have the mean and the variance of the 5 variables of interest. I can plot the variance with error bars, but when I try to do it with geom_smooth()/stat_smooth() it doesn't work well.

```
   ggplot(data = df4, aes(x = times, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value-var, ymax = value+var))+
        geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = value-var, xmax = value+var))+ geom_smooth()
```

[Output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/folsC.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you want `geom_ribbon` instead?  Consider making your question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding an small example dataset to go along with your code.

Comment: It worked! Do you know how to I change the color of the shadow, so it will be as the color of the lines?

Comment: Use `fill` rather than `color`. `color` will only change the outline of 2d areas.